# stripslashes_deep vs htmlspecialchars

Tags: php

What's better for making links, stripslashes_deep or htmlspecialchars?

For example, if I have to make a link like:

```
http://my-link?something=46&something=something else&some-more-variables="Everything but the opera"
```

(not my link design, by the way)

Is it better to use stripslashes on "Everything but the opera" part (that the user entered in quotes) or is it better to use htmlspecialchars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `urlencode()` if you are using get variables (aka variables in the url).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using it as part of an url, it's best to use `urlencode($str)` for the "Everything but the opera" part.

(see http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)